# Performing the equivalent of chattr +i filename.txt from Linux application

Tags: c, linux

Is there any interface in the Linux userspace API that will allow me to perform the action equivalent to

```
chattr +i myfile
chattr -i myfile
```

If possible I need to do this from within my application but I cannot find anything online that suggests how one would go about doing this from the Linux API. I would have thought there would be some kind of `ioctl` call available to do this but I simply cannot find any details about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at:

- http://www.danlj.org/lad/src/setflags.c.html

and if you do some `strace` on chattr, you could have found out that it calls stuff that looks like:

```
ioctl(fd, EXT2_IOC_SETFLAGS, flags)
```

(have a look at [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.security.audit/3904))

Comment: Thanks very much, the strace suggestion is excellent. Unfortunately as I am using uclibc, busybox and crosstools on an embedded system I have no EXT2_IOC_SETFLAGS but on my system there is a FS_IOC32_SETGFLAGS which works out fine. Thanks again

Comment: I believe the quotation above shoud be `ioctl(fd, EXT2_IOC_SETFLAGS, &flags)`

Comment: well, you're right and you're not right. I only used flags to show off that there's something that we can call `flags`, with a focus on the `EXT2_IOC_SETFLAGS` attribute. That thing called flags can be an `int*` where my code would be right or an `int` (like in the linked document) and your belief is right. Either way, I did not declare what `flags` is in my snippet, the important point being to go read some documentation on how to use ioctl and the setflags! ;-)